# Rails 3 Action Malier renders template and doesn't send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

It has been asked million times probably but my case is different and I have tried every config option imaginable and tried in production mode as well. The email is rendered but it doesn't appear anywhere. I even bought $15 MockSMPT app to see the emails but nothing goes out it seems.

Here are the configs for MockSMTP:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "localhost",
  :port => 1025,
  :domain => "whatever.com"
}
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I have tried every `delivery_method`, `:test`, `:file`, I am ripping my hair off, nothing helps:

```
Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (2.1ms)
```

And this is it.

Code for sending is trivial:

```
def contact_email(contact, house=nil)
  @house=house if house
  @contact=contact
  mail(to: contact.email, subject: "#{contact.name} new inquiry")
end
```

`Rails 3.2.8`

`contact_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  if @contact.valid?
    @house=House.find_by_id(params[:house_id])
    ContactMailer::contact_email @contact, @house
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you send emails, and the version of rails that you are using?

Comment: The code where you are actually calling the mailer action, somewhere in the controller may be?

Comment: Here you go, but I think it's the mailer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

`ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact, @house).deliver`

You can read ActionMailer documentation here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Your statement just  creates Mail::Message object, deliver actually sends the email.